# Can Casey White be held accountable for the death of Vicky White?

Tags: united-states, murder

Can Casey White be held accountable for the suicide / death of Vicky White?

https://abcnews.go.com/US/escaped-murder-suspect-extremely-violent-medication-sheriff/story?id=84590527

In Texas, if one of two bank robbers dies in the course of robbery, I understand that the survivor can be held accountable.

Answer (score 4):

### No

[Felony murder](https://banksbrower.com/2020/01/31/felony-murder-how-it-is-possible-to-be-convicted-of-murder-without-killing-anyone/) in Indiana is limited to participants in the following criminal activities only:

- Burglary
- Child molest
- Arson
- Rape
- Kidnapping
- Robbery
- Carjacking
- Drug Dealing/Manufacturing

AFAIK, the pair were not doing any of those.

Comment: FWIW, there might be civil liability even though there might not be criminal liability.

Comment: @ohwilleke Casey is likely judgement proof

Comment: A tort judgment in a case like this would not be discharged in bankruptcy if the tort creditor took the proper steps in the proceeding. Someone who is judgment proof now, might not be fifteen years later.

Comment: @ohwilleke he’s in jail for 75 years - unless he gets an unexpected bequest he’s never going to have enough money.